# Size of image in bytes, without saving to disk Python

Tags: python-3.x, image, base64, python-imaging-library

Im trying to get the size of an image that is sent via http request encoded as base64. On the file system the image is a .png image and is around 1,034,023 bytes, however when I receive the image as base64 and get the size in bytes its smaller i.e 840734.

Is this correct and is this due to the compression of .png being different to the image loaded in memory? And if i want he size of the image that is displayed in the file system will I have to re save this image to disk when i receive it?

to get the size of the image in bytes I have the following functions (both return the same value). Im using Python3.

```
def image_size(imageb64):
    character_count = len(imageb64)
    padding_count = imageb64[character_count:None].count('=')
    count = (3 * (character_count / 4)) - padding_count
    print(f'Image size count: {count}')

def image_to_size_in_bytes(numpy_img):
    img = Image.fromarray(numpy_img)
    buffered = BytesIO()
    img.save(buffered, format='PNG')
    contents = buffered.getvalue()
    print(f'IMAGE SIZE: {len(contents)}')
```

Comment: If you decode the base64 into a file, how do they compare when you check both files with a tool such as `pngcheck`? It is possible your locally compressed PNG is far worse compressed.

Comment: @usr2564301 hey, no one is comparing this its just me testing the service locally, I want to reject images over a certain size but the image on disk which im testing with outputs a different size when i try to get the size of the image in memory.

Comment: Hold on – I might be unclear on your question. ".. the image loaded in memory ..", why bother about that? An image 'loaded' gets uncompressed, and thus uses more memory than the same compressed *file*. Is that your worry?

Comment: I have the image loaded in memory because its sent to the service as a parameter in a HTTP Request as base 64.

my worry is that when testing locally the image in the filesystem when selecting image properties will say the size is 1,034,023 bytes but when i use the functions above to get the size in bytes from the base64 string the size in bytes is smaller i.e 840734 bytes @usr2564301

Comment: Are you by any chance confusing *data size* (the number of pixels times the number of channels) with *file size* (the size on disk/in transfer *when compressed*)? For an outlier, see this [4,096x4,096 rgb image](http://www.libpng.com/pub/png/img_png/16million-pschmidt.png) which occupies less than 60K on disk.